# Finding Latest Date Based on Dataset in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dataset in 2 separate worksheets.

In worksheet one, we keep track of website's that we have scanned and when we have scanned them last. Each website will have multiple rows of data as each site is typically scanned each week.

In worksheet two, we have our database of websites that we can along with additional info pertaining to those websites.

I am wondering if there is a formula that we can use in worksheet two that will pull the last date scanned from our data in worksheet one?

A reference spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clrqDaWiKa2xCAgdZxcVfW_g06MmG7LSrp_fUDF0_Sw/edit?usp=sharing

I would like the "Date Last Scanned" in worksheet two to show the most recent date shown in column B on worksheet one.

Thanks in advance!

I have a dataset in 2 separate worksheets.

In worksheet one, we keep track of website's that we have scanned and when we have scanned them last. Each website will have multiple rows of data as each site is typically scanned each week.

In worksheet two, we have our database of websites that we can along with additional info pertaining to those websites.

I am wondering if there is a formula that we can use in worksheet two that will pull the last date scanned from our data in worksheet one?

A reference spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1clrqDaWiKa2xCAgdZxcVfW_g06MmG7LSrp_fUDF0_Sw/edit?usp=sharing

I would like the "Date Last Scanned" in worksheet two to show the most recent date shown in column B on worksheet one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74739691/edit) the question to remove repetition. Also show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in cell `'Dataset 2'!C2`:

`=to_date( maxifs('Dataset 1'!B$2:B, 'Dataset 1'!A$2:A, B2) )`

Format the cell as **Format > Number > Date** or another date format of your preference. Then copy the cell down as far as needed.